# Item de un color u otro (RecyclerView)

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, cardview

Lo que quiero conseguir es lo siguiente, que un elemento se pinte de un color y el siguiente de otro:

```
-----------
item0: azul
-----------
item1: amarillo
-----------
item2: azul
-----------
item3: amarillo
-----------
...
```

y así sin fin, es decir, utilizar dos colores diferentes y que cada item vaya teniendo el color que no tiene el de arriba.

De momento lo que he conseguido es asignarlo yo, pero uno por uno..

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecordatoriosViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Recordatorios singleRecordatorios = listRecordatorioses.get(position);
        if(position==1)
            holder.cardview_item.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        else if(position==2)
            holder.cardview_item.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
```

Comment: En la primera posición , la variable position tiene valor de 0 no de 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto me parece que ya lo realizaste, recuerda que `position` es el indice de cada elemento (inicia con 0 no lo olvides), puedes definir cada uno manualmente pero lo mejor es determinar cuando un numero es par (0 es considerado par) o impar

```
private boolean esPar(int n){
    if ( ( n % 2 ) == 0 ) {
        return true; //Par
    } else {
        return false;//Impar
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aplicando a tu código sería de esta forma:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecordatoriosViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Recordatorios singleRecordatorios = listRecordatorioses.get(position);
        if((position % 2) == 0)
            holder.cardview_item.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        else 
            holder.cardview_item.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
...
}
```

Comment: Jorgesys, tienes tiempo para un chat?

Comment: @sioesi si claro.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147214/dudas-java-y-android

Answer (score 2):

Puedes verificar si la posicion del item es par o impar, asi va asignando a azul o amarillo segun corresponda

```
if(position%2==0){
   holder.cardview_item.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
} else {
   holder.cardview_item.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
}
```